# Same First Answer reappears in queue after being deleted

Tags: support, review

I just opened a First Answer in the review queue on English Language Learning. I switched tabs to read the question and gloss over the other answers. When getting back to the answer, it had been deleted. Since 'Looks OK' is the only option left that makes sense, I selected it. I was then brought to the next task, which, strangely enough, was the same answer.

[This](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/134578) is that 'second' answer, which still exists.

Is there a logical explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user posted two (almost) identical answers, perhaps by accident, and deleted the [first one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/315625/41273) ([review](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/134577)).

Comment: Yeah, I just now realized that could have been the case. I posted a comment, but this clears that up. Thanks :)